# In dcc.DatePickerRange, I want to display only the text box for entering the date range and hide the popup calendar

Tags: plotly-dash

As the title says, I want to display only the textbox. I would like to hide or delete the calendar, but I don't think there is such a feature at the moment.
What should I do?

[image]

make only the text box visible